# How to fetch data on react-spline Mouse click on 3d object?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, 3d, fetch, spline

So I want do call `await fetch("myurl")` on click and redraw 2d UI parts after that. How to do it in [react-spline](https://github.com/splinetool/react-spline#listen-to-events) event call on 3d scene?